# How to date make a file name in linux

Tags: linux

I try to backup a file in crontab but the date to save a specific folder

In crontab

> crontab -e

```
* * * * * echo "hi i am safwan" >> /home/safwan/linx/backup/"$(date +"%Y_%m_%d").bak"
```

But no backup of the file.

What is the solution?

Comment: `%` is a special character in `crontab` and have to be doubled. https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/crontab.5.html

Answer (score 2):

You use nested double quotes without escaping the inner ones.

This would work:

```
"$(date +\"%Y_%m_%d\").bak"
```

However, all these quotes are unnecessary. You can remove them all.

EDIT:

As pointed out in one of the comments to the original question, there is a second problem: `%` is special character in crontab, so you have to escape it:

```
$(date +\%Y_\%m_\%d).bak
```